# Toggling a text on button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a dark mode toggle button and I require following text properties :-

1. `Turn on dark mode` should appear when theme is a light one
2. `Turn off dark mode` should appear if theme is dark one.

Nothing more, Currently, I'm using follwing code to toggle between dark and light mode but the issue comes with button. I tried different codes but the text gets swapped in a wrong manner.
https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/oNxrxad.

```
<script>const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  document.body.classList.add("dark"); 
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark");

  let theme = "light";
  if (document.body.classList.contains("dark")) {
    theme = "dark"; 
 
  }

  localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
});
</script>
<style>
.btn-toggle {
border-radius: 20px;
float: center;
outline: none;
border: 25px;
padding: 10px;
width: fit;
font-size: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
text-align:center;
box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #5c5c5f, 
             -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
background-color: #101010;
color: #e6e7ee;
}
body.dark .btn-toggle {
box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #121212, 
             -5px -5px 10px #4a4a4a;
color: #101010 !important;
background-color: #e6e7ee;
}
body.dark .btn-toggle a {
color: #101010 !important;
}
body {background-color: #e6e7ee}
body.dark {background-color: #101010; color:#ffffff}
</style>
<button class="btn-toggle" id="btn-id"></button>
```

Comment: Hi Maniac, good to see you at SO! Try CSS like `.btn-toggle::before { content: 'dark mode' . } body.dark .btn-toggle::before { content: 'light mode' }`

Comment: I just tested your Codepen with my suggestion (you will need to remove the trailing dot from the 1st rule, sorry about that `.btn-toggle::before { content: 'dark mode' }`) and it works as expected. Change the text to anything you need/like. No need for Javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you don't really need Javascript to get things done:

Logic:

- when `.dark` is off, show text 1 - this is the default
- when `.dark` is on, show text 2 - when CSS class `.dark` is active

CSS:

```
/* ADDED */
.btn-toggle::before { content: 'dark mode' }       /* default text of the button */
.dark .btn-toggle::before { content: 'light mode' }/* overwrite the default text*/
/*********/
```